# Android Can't Access newly created folder

Tags: android

I am developing a Note App that store file in external sd card. File Management is also a part of app. App allow user to create folder. I use this code. 
file.mkdir();

After that I refresh my ListView;

I can see newly created folder in listView. But i can't acess it( click it) immediately. I have to wait for a while to be able to access it. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

Before setting new adapter to listView, set null to setAdapter().

I add

listView.setAdapter(null);//this make listView empty

listView.setAdapter(adapter);//fill listView with new Data..